# Rewrite rules not working after cloning to a new server

Tags: .htaccess

I am stuck with what seems to be a poorly written site. I have cloned the site to my server to make changes in a safe environment but can't seem to get the sub pages to render with the rewrite rules. I did notice that the original long argument does render the page so I have narrowed it to the htaccess file and it seems to be the rules. Here is the file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /otherpages/

#AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .php

RewriteRule ^index.html$ ./index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us.html$ ./cntc_page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us-action.html$ ./cntc_page_action.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact-us-successful.html$ ./cntc_page_success.php [L]

#company list page
#RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./company_list.php?category_title=$1&start=$2&order=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./company_list.php?category_title=$1&limit=$2&start=$3&order=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./company_list.php?category_title=$1&limit=$2&start=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./company_list.php?category_title=$1&start=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*).html$ ./company_list.php?category_title=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category.html$ ./company_list.php [L]
RewriteRule ^sub-category/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./sub_category_list.php?category_title=$1&start=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^sub-category/([^/]*).html$ ./sub_category_list.php?category_title=$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^company-list/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./sub_company_list.php?category_title=$1&sub_cat_title=$2&limit=$3&start=$4&order=$5 [L]

RewriteRule ^company-list/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./sub_company_list.php?category_title=$1&sub_cat_title=$2&limit=$3&start=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^company-list/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./sub_company_list.php?category_title=$1&sub_cat_title=$2&limit=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^company-list/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./sub_company_list.php?category_title=$1&sub_cat_title=$2 [L]

#detail page
RewriteRule ^company/([^/]*).html$ ./company_detail.php?company_title=$1 [L]

#content pages
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*).html$ ./content_page.php?page_title=$1 [L]


#events page
RewriteRule ^events-list/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./event_list.php?start=$1&sort_ord=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^events-list/([^/]*).html$ ./event_list.php?start=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^events-list.html$ ./event_list.php [L]
RewriteRule ^event-details/([^/]*).html$ ./event_detail.php?event_title=$1 [L]

#search page
RewriteRule ^search-company/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./search_company.php?search_keyword=$1&start=$2&sort_ord=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^search-company/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./search_company.php?search_keyword=$1&start=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^search-company/([^/]*).html$ ./search_company.php?search_keyword=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search-company.html$ ./search_company.php [L]

#search events
RewriteRule ^search-events/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./event_search.php?search_keyword=$1&start=$2&sort_ord=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^search-events/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ./event_search.php?search_keyword=$1&start=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^search-events/([^/]*).html$ ./event_search.php?search_keyword=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^search-events.html$ ./event_search.php [L]

#coupons
RewriteRule ^q-perks/([^/]*).html$ ./coupons.php?start=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^q-perks.html$ ./coupons.php [L]

#printed edition
RewriteRule ^the-printed-edition.html$ ./printed_edition.php [L]
RewriteRule ^the-printed-edition-action.html$ ./printed_edition_action.php [L]
RewriteRule ^the-printed-edition-successful.html$ ./printed_edition_success.php [L]

#print
RewriteRule ^print-page/([^/]*).html$ ./print_page.php?coupon_title=$1 [L]
```

This file is identical to the one on their current server besides the Rewrite base and I have to comment out `AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .php`as it would prompt me to download the site or some file... I know the mod_rewrite is turned on and everything else configured correctly as I have other sites that are using the rewrite engine with no issue. What else could be wrong here? I am not fluent in the htaccess arena and really server configuration for matter. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What URL are you trying to go to that is failing and where is the php files located (in the `/otherpages/` directory?)

Comment: you can view the site here: cvfstrategies.com Most all php files are in the root. The whole directory structure is confusing and nothing I am familiar with. You will see that the url does load as the rewritten url but I get a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Most all php files are in the root.

Why do you have:

```
RewriteBase /otherpages/
```

if your php files are in your document root? It looks like all of these php files that you're rewriting to are in the document root as I can do to links like: `http://cvfstrategies.com/company_list.php?category_title=accomodations` just fine. Change the baee to:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Wow. Well I feel like an idiot. :) This wasn't working before...\Thanks